# Are there any performance differences when using vw/vh vs rem/em/px?

Tags: html, css, sass

I was told using `vh` and `vw` causes a repaint, thus causing hits to performance, but I couldn't find sufficient research on this topic.

Additionally, in what context should each measurement be used? For example, if I wanted to use `vh` or `vw` on something like `padding`, is that wrong? Is it better suited to use it for positioning purposes?

I hope this question makes sense, because I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: It completely depends on what layout you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Performance issues are mostly caused by JavaScript code and not by CSS. Although some of the units that are used in CSS can have some impact. This impact is small so always use the unit that you can use to achieve something. If you want a full page div for example, you always have to use vh for the height, but you can use % for the width. Use what you need depending on what you want to achieve.

Other example, maybe you want a padding to be larger or smaller depending on the size of the text, you can not achieve this with px, so you have to use em or rem.

px is the best performance since it doesn't need any calculations, although, sometimes it is hard to achieve something with only using px.